# grass region resolution error

Tags: raster, grass-gis, resolution, region

I am working on a raster, but I can't set a correct region for it.
In the **Set region to match this raster map** field, I select my raster map to change current region, but its resolution does not change. once I run an analysis command on my raster, I see the following error:

```
 elevation file's resolution differs from current region resolution!
```

please help me to change current region resolution to match my raster map.

Comment: The command to set the current "computional" region to match a raster is:  g.region -p rast=<your rastermap>. This will also print out the resulting region. To check that it indeed matches the region of the raster, run: r.info <your raster map> and examine the resolution in both outputs to verify that they are identical.

Comment: Please add which command you use.

Comment: Sometimes you might need to add the `-a` flag to the `g.region` instruction. Please, handle this **with care**!